# Securing a mobile customer loyalty card

Tags: security, one-time-password

Imagine you're programming a WebApp that does nothing more than display a virtual customer card, with which the customer can identify himself at your store. It must not be possible for the customer to copy his customer card to friends and family members, so the QR/bar-code must be dynamic. The common practice would be to regularly transfer a new seed from the server and the WebApp would then generate an OTP depending on the time.

The problem is that the algorithm is executed locally and the seed of a WebApp is not in a protected area of the smartphone. The user could then pass the seed on and someone with a FakeApp could, for example, generate a fake card for the next X minutes and use the customer benefits in another store if they are not networked (double-spending).

So it would be safest to send the OTP in short time intervals from the server and nothing is generated locally. But then the problem is that the WebApp doesn't work any more, as soon as the internet connection breaks down and this is still often the case in shops with thick walls.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting webapp as mobile app, you can solve this problem with software attestation.  Software attestation is a process where the actual code being run is fingerprinted and you can then verify that the signature you see running is the signature you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the disclosure, but since this answer stands without the disclosure, it's best to remove it all together.